# How to save the ArrayList<Route> in Sharedpreferecnce?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have latlng list of geopoints

```
  ArrayList<Route> arrayList
```

I am saving this by

```
 SharedPreferences prefeMain = MainActivitybatchGrp1.this.getSharedPreferences("APPLICATION", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefeMain.edit();

    try {
        Log.e("TASK","Success");
        editor.putString("GROUPA", ObjectSerializer.serialize(arrayListLatLong));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TASK","Fail:: "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    editor.commit();
```

But it gives an IOException

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.directions.route.Route
```

Comment: just google your error man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a class does not implement java.io.Serializable (like what you have in your case) you can convert it to JSON and store the JSON on the `SharedPreferences`.

Of course you will also need to deserialize the JSON string from the `SharedPreferences`.

Here is an example for serialization / de-serialization with the popular GSON library:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;

public class GsonTest {

    private static class Test1213 {

        public Test1213(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testConversion() throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Test1213 john_doe1 = new Test1213("John Doe");
        String john_doe = gson.toJson(john_doe1);
        System.out.println(john_doe);
        Test1213 test1213 = gson.fromJson(john_doe, Test1213.class);
        assertThat(john_doe1.getName(), is(test1213.getName()));
    }
}
```

This test serializes to JSON and back.

This is the serialized JSON:

```
{"name":"John Doe"}
```